# Is it possible to use the Oracle sql WITH CLAUSE on multiple unrelated queries within the same file?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have an SQL script that generates a report through SQL plus. The report is generated by running multiple unrelated queries one after the other. 
Some of the queries have common code that i would like to try and only define once. As an example, assume the report generation file contains the following two scripts

```
Select a, b, c
from x
where a in (
    select x
    From d where x like '%ABC%'
)
/

Select a, d, y
from z
where a in (
    select x
    From d where x like '%ABC%'
)
/
```

The two queries are completely different but both use the same subquery. 
I would like to avoid having to rewrite the subquery for each independent query.

The WITH clause can be used but i am not sure how to use it on two different queries

```
with t1 as (
 select x
 from d where x like '%ABC%'
)
Select a, b, c
from x, t1
where t1.x = x.a
```

The above resolves it for the first query. How can i use the same WITH statement for the second query? or is there an alternative approach to achieve this?

Edit

One other option is to use refcursors. This might work but i might be very tedious to build the strings for each query and concatenate it with a generic string query. As it is a plsql block, it will also be difficult to generate headers between the different queries.

```
Declare
    v_sql varchar(2000);
Begin
    v_sql := 'Select 1 from dual';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
    Open :x for v_sql;
End;
/
print x;
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't.  Why not create a view?

Comment: Yes a view would work but would prefer to avoid having to create a view for each report.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a common table expression (CTE) for multiple queries.  This is functionality for a single query.

I would recommend a view or a temporary table.